# probability of making passwords

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we have ﬁve symbols available, say a, b, c, d, e.  One plan is to form passwords by using diﬀerent orderings of these ﬁve symbols.  A second plan is to use ordered strings of length ﬁve, with each symbol in the string chosen from these symbols, in which any symbol can be used one or more times.  How many diﬀerent passwords are possible in each plan?

Answer (score 1):

**First method**:

There are $5$ choices for the first letter. For each of these, there are $4$ choices for the second letter, and for each of *those* there are $3$ choices for the third letter. There are $2$ choices for the fourth letter, and the fifth letter is fixed by choosing the others. This gives us $$ 5! = 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1= \boxed{120 \text{ passwords}}$$

---

**Second method**:

For each of the five password slots, there are $5$ choices ($5$ different letters that could go in each slot). Thus, there are $$5^5 = 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = \boxed{3125 \text{ passwords}}$$